# php echo does not write what I want

Tags: php

I'm trying to do a simple echo to get the style attributes of a hr element. This attributes are placed in a data field but I lost the second part of the field.

I do this:

```
<hr id="lineDemo" style=<?php echo $model->css_style; ?> />
```

$model->css_style has this inside:

```
"height: 5px; background-color: rgb(0, 253, 255);"
```

What I obtained is this...

```
<hr id="lineDemo" style="height: 5px;">
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are the quote signs actually included inside css_style property?

Comment: Yes. I've tried to do the same excluding quote signs in the property.

Comment: This code should work. Can you show more code of `$model`?

Comment: Yeah Javier. Show more code of $model.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should put the  into quotes so that the whole string is part of the attribute:

```
<hr id="lineDemo" style="<?php echo $model->css_style; ?>" />
```

This might help but maybe not entirely (depending on what really is in $model->css_style...)

Comment: This is what i get now:

        <hr id="lineDemo" style="" height:="" 5px;="" background-color:="" rgb(0,="" 253,="" 255);""="">

Comment: Then probably you have in css_style something else than what you think?

Answer (score 0):

Try following

`<hr id="lineDemo" style="<?=$model->css_style?>" />`

Comment: Thanks Lepanto. This is the right answer. No quotes in database field and your code.

Answer (score -1):

You don't have quote signs of

```
<hr id="lineDemo" style=<?php echo $model->css_style; ?> />
```

line. Could you try this one:

```
<hr id="lineDemo" style="<?php echo $model->css_style; ?>" />
```

Comment: How is this any different from what has all ready been suggested?